# My Header Color doesn't change when publishing the Website

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, header, wordpress-theming

I am working with Porto Theme and when changing the header/Footer Colors doesn't affect when publishing but I can see the changes I made only when open the theme options dashboard like in the pictures below.
[image: The Live Website]
[image: customizing website dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

I it's looks like cache issue, please check your site in private window or after clear the cache, or Might be some CSS load in front and that have CSS for header color with `!important`, please check with that.